# Savitzky-Golay filter plots wrong values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using the Savitzky-Golay filter to smooth my data. I ran into a list of values that fall very quickly to values close to 0.0. The following figure is the original data:

[image: original data]

After applying the Savitzky-Golay filter, I get the following:

[image: smoothed]

We can see that it plots values below 0.0, which is wrong.

Here is the function I use:

```
def savitzky_golay(y, window_size, order, deriv=0, rate=1):
    r"""Smooth (and optionally differentiate) data with a Savitzky-Golay filter.
    The Savitzky-Golay filter removes high frequency noise from data.
    It has the advantage of preserving the original shape and
    features of the signal better than other types of filtering
    approaches, such as moving averages techniques.
    Parameters
    ----------
    y : array_like, shape (N,)
        the values of the time history of the signal.
    window_size : int
        the length of the window. Must be an odd integer number.
    order : int
        the order of the polynomial used in the filtering.
        Must be less then `window_size` - 1.
    deriv: int
        the order of the derivative to compute (default = 0 means only smoothing)
    Returns
    -------
    ys : ndarray, shape (N)
        the smoothed signal (or it's n-th derivative).
    Notes
    -----
    The Savitzky-Golay is a type of low-pass filter, particularly
    suited for smoothing noisy data. The main idea behind this
    approach is to make for each point a least-square fit with a
    polynomial of high order over a odd-sized window centered at
    the point.
    Examples
    --------
    t = np.linspace(-4, 4, 500)
    y = np.exp( -t**2 ) + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, t.shape)
    ysg = savitzky_golay(y, window_size=31, order=4)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(t, y, label='Noisy signal')
    plt.plot(t, np.exp(-t**2), 'k', lw=1.5, label='Original signal')
    plt.plot(t, ysg, 'r', label='Filtered signal')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    References
    ----------
    .. [1] A. Savitzky, M. J. E. Golay, Smoothing and Differentiation of
       Data by Simplified Least Squares Procedures. Analytical
       Chemistry, 1964, 36 (8), pp 1627-1639.
    .. [2] Numerical Recipes 3rd Edition: The Art of Scientific Computing
       W.H. Press, S.A. Teukolsky, W.T. Vetterling, B.P. Flannery
       Cambridge University Press ISBN-13: 9780521880688
    """
    import numpy as np
    from math import factorial

    try:
        window_size = np.abs(np.int(window_size))
        order = np.abs(np.int(order))
    except ValueError, msg:
        raise ValueError("window_size and order have to be of type int")
    if window_size % 2 != 1 or window_size < 1:
        raise TypeError("window_size size must be a positive odd number")
    if window_size < order + 2:
        raise TypeError("window_size is too small for the polynomials order")
    order_range = range(order+1)
    half_window = (window_size -1) // 2
    # precompute coefficients
    b = np.mat([[k**i for i in order_range] for k in range(-half_window, half_window+1)])
    m = np.linalg.pinv(b).A[deriv] * rate**deriv * factorial(deriv)
    # pad the signal at the extremes with
    # values taken from the signal itself
    firstvals = y[0] - np.abs( y[1:half_window+1][::-1] - y[0] )
    lastvals = y[-1] + np.abs(y[-half_window-1:-1][::-1] - y[-1])
    y = np.concatenate((firstvals, y, lastvals))
    return np.convolve( m[::-1], y, mode='valid')
```

Does anybody know why and how to fix it?

Comment: This filter is implemented in `scipy.signal.savgol_filter`. Are you using a uniformally sampled data? It won't work otherwise (i.e. you would need to interpolate it on a uniformally sampled grid). Otherwise try reducing the order of your polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Such a thing is typical for several interpolating/ smoothing techniques, which are based on **polynomials**. (I did not calculate whether you have an actual 1/x function here.) Approximating a function like 1/x will probably give you overshooting to negative values (how often and how much depends on the order  of Polynomials you use: n-th order might give you n-1 changes in sign).
A "fix" would be to use optimize.curve_fit() instead of a filter and define your function as something like

```
def f(x, a, b, c, d): 
     return a/(x-b)**c + d
```